# What natural supplements exist to lower LDL cholesterol and raise HDL cholesterol?

Tags: heart-disease, cardiology, cardiovascular-disease, cholesterol

The doctor told me to use Niacin or Red Yeast to reduce cholesterol. Examine.com, which seems to be pretty legit, [seems to support using Garlic as a natural alternative](http://examine.com/stacks/cholesterol/). What supplements exist with solid scientific research to backup the claims of reducing LDL and increasing HDL?